# Can we send push notifications on mobile without mobile app using phone number from Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, notifications, push, send

Can we send push notifications on mobile without mobile app using phone number From node js?

Comment: If all you have is a phone number, then the best you can do is send SMS. If the user is running a PWA or similar that you control then it is possible for you to register for and receive push notifications, iff the user allows you to.

Comment: @Michael , can we send notification at browser ?

Comment: Yes in the right conditions, this should get you started: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/